# Taylor's expansion for $f(t,y(t))$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Using Taylor's expansion, show that for every $t\in[t_0,T]$
    it is true that:
    $$f(t,y(t))\ \approx\ f(t_k,y_k) + (t-t_k)f_t(t_k,y_k) + (t-t_k)f(t_k,y_k)f_y(t_k,y_k)\,.$$

For this problem we have that \begin{equation}\label{eqn:ode:1}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
y^{\prime} & = & f(t,y)\,,\; \text{for } t_0\leq t\leq T\\[0.5ex]
y(t_0) & = & y_0
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

The only thing that occurs to me is to use Taylor for several variables, that is $$ f(t,y(t))=f(t_k,y(t_k)) +(t-t_k)f_t(t_k,y(t_k))+(t-t_k)f_y(t_k,y(t_k)) + \cdots$$

however, I have no idea how to proceed, someone could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align}
g(t):= f(t, y(t))
\end{align}
then Taylor expanding $g(t)$ about $t=t_k$ yields
\begin{align}
g(t) = g(t_k) + g'(t_k)(t-t_k)+\mathcal{O}(|t-t_k|^2)
\end{align}
when $|t-t_k|$ is sufficiently small. In particular, we see that
\begin{align}
g'(t) =&\ \partial_t f(t, y(t))+\partial_yf(t, y(t))y'(t)\\
=&\ \partial_t f(t, y(t))+\partial_yf(t, y(t))f(t, y(t))
\end{align}
Hence we have the desired result.